# Feats that make Intimidate a class skill

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills

What feats (if any) can turn Intimidate into a class skill?

Comment: Without some kind of information that limits the possible answers (such as an existing build that it has to fit into), this is too broad.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't feel that way. Given the system, there are very limited ways to use the media requested (feats) to accomplish the goal of getting a specific skill as a class skill. In fact, I think Anne Aunyme may have found the only one. They goal can't typically be accomplished through feats, so it's not so much a list as 1 or 2 options.

Answer (score 13):

You can take [Additional Traits](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/additional-traits/) and then any one of these traits that gives you what you are looking for, like [Omen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/faith-traits/omen/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Bully Breed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/bully-breed/) (from horror adventures) to turn Intimidate into a class skill for your mount or animal companion.

Answer (score 2):

At level 1, you can take [Hermean Blood](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/hermean-blood/).  For some reason the SRD is calling it Island Blood.  You could also take [Cosmopolitan](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/cosmopolitan/).  Both these feats allow you to make two skills class skills.

Hermean Blood requires them to both use the same ability score, while Cosmopolitan requires them both to be Intelligence-, Wisdom-, or Charisma-based skills.

As mentioned by @Anne Aunyme, Additional Traits can grant you intimidate as a class skill depending on what trait you pick.

Comment: The reason for the name change of feats, spells, prestige classes and traits is normally due to intellectual property of paizo.

Answer (score -2):

There's a giant list here: http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?491181-Alternative-ways-to-get-new-Class-skills&p=20885236#post20885236

It's 3.5, but that's usable in many pathfinder games.

Comment: I haven't played any Pathfinder game that counted content sourced from 3.5 as available, except one that was essentially 'you can ask and probably not get it'.